# who create chat room in lan messenger

Tags: chat

In our company we are using [lan messenger](http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/index.php) for communications. In this application there is a facility to create a chat room and add other users to it and then when we send a message, all users in this room see messages.

But there is a problem that no one can detect who created this chat room and who added me to it

Is there a way to know this?